# Question about "this" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, scope, this, curly-braces

This may be a newbie question.  I've used javascript for years but have only started to get "serious" about it.  I have a question about "this"

```
var defaults = {
    baseId : 'item_',
    baseName : this.baseId
}

console.log('defaults',defaults);
```

Not sure why defaults.baseName is "undefined"  How does one reference stuff in the curly braces?  Is it possible, or do I really have to type 'item_' twice?

Comment: I would suggest you do a `var prefix = 'item_'` and use that to append to you map's values when you need it

Comment: also take a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript object literal is a syntatic sugar therefore it does not work.

```
this; // at point A
var defaults = {
    baseId : 'item_',
    baseName : this.baseId
}
```

translates to

```
this; // point A
var defaults = new Object();
defaults.baseId = 'item_';
defaults.baseName = this.baseId; // "this" here is same as "this" at point A
```

You can use getters and setters.

```
{
   baseId: 'item_',
   get baseName() { return this.baseId; },
   set baseName(x) { this.baseId = x }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that you cannot do what you're trying to do.  During the parse/interpretation/evaluation (however you want to think about it) of the object literal, it doesn't exist and so it can't be referred to in any way like that.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
var defaults = {};
defaults.baseId = defaults.baseName = 'item_';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `function` instead, creating the equivalent of `class`:

```
function defaults() {
   this.baseId = 'item_';
   this.baseName = this.baseId;
}
```

Now `this` will have the proper context.

Another option, using your original code, is making `baseName` a function:

```
var defaults = {
    baseId : 'item_',
    baseName : function() { return  this.baseId; }
};
```

Thanks Šime Vidas for the correction!

Comment: You don't have to write `defaults` twice. You can write: `return this.baseId;`